# How do I share a photo with a message on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, sharing

I'm stuck on a problem that I thought should be simple.  I have two image buttons on an activity:  one is "rate"; the other is "share". What I want is when a person clicks "share" it posts an image and message to their timeline.

I've already have the facebook sdk integrated, so here is the code I was trying to use:

```
public ImageButton imgbutton3, imgbutton2;
public CallbackManager callbackManager;
public ShareDialog shareDialog;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.game_console);

    imgbutton3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    imgbutton3.setOnClickListener(ImgClickListener);
    imgbutton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imgbutton2.setOnClickListener(ImgClickListener);


}

 private View.OnClickListener ImgClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()      {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton3:
                //post to facebook...
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this); //(stuck here! :( )



                break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                //do a google rating....
                break;

        }
    }


};
```

The share dialog has a squiggly red line under it saying it cannot resolve the method.  What am I supposed to do here?  I want the sharedialog to show and pass on an image and text after the button is clicked but it isn't allowing me to have any methods within the onclicklistener method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
     ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentTitle(strTitle).setContentDescription(strDesc).setImageUrl(uri).
                                .setContentUrl(android.net.Uri.parse(extractLinks(strDesc))).build();
                        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ViewFacebook.this);
                        shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
                        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, mShareDialog);

 private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> mShareDialog = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewFacebook.this, "Publish Success!"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(ViewFacebook.this,
                    "Publish cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewFacebook.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: ViewFacebook does not exist.  Where did you get this from???  It is not part of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: its just activity instance.you can take your activity instance.

Comment: the ".show();" part of your code comes up red in my ide.  I tried to retype it again, but "show" doesn't come up in the intellisense.